# Saving ArrayList of Hash map

Tags: android

in my app i want to save data at `savedInstanceState()`. i want to save `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`. And so far i am unable to do that. 
 here is my code that is bothering me

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("places", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) places);

    }
```

restore() method

```
private void restore(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //What should i do here! i have try many things but none of them is helping

    }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since `ArrayList`, `HashMap` and `String` are `Serializable` you can use `Bundle.putSerializable` and `Bundle.getSerializable`

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("places", places);
}

private void restore(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        places = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("places"); 
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you are calling `restore` from `onRestoreInstanceState` or `onCreate`

Comment: Thank from me too! Also just to add if you use onRestoreInstanceState you don't have to do the null check. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0):

lets say u have:

```
    ArrayList< HashMap< String,String>> arr = new ArrayList< HashMap< String,String>> ();

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("places", (ArrayList<    ? extends Parcelable>) arr);
    }

   @Override
   protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> a = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>)savedInstanceState.get("places");
   /*for(int i =0; i< a.size(); i++){
        HashMap<String,String> map = a.get(i);
        for(String s : map.keySet()){
            Log.d("log",s+" :: "+map.get(s));
        }
    }*/
}
```